# How to change archive status of the data of the last five records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation in which i want to show the latest five records in DESC order.If a new record comes into these five records then archive status of the record  with id=1 should be updated to true, and should now be moved to archived page. I am a new bee in ruby on rails please help.

Thanks

Comment: Ruby 2.x or Ruby 3.x ?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the model to create and store records
Lets say you are using Post model that has several fields to store some info. Note that id attribute and create/update fields are automatically created by Rails for you, and you can use them.
You can create a model by calling the following command in terminal window in your app directory

```
rails generate model Post author:string content:string #add any otehr attributes you wish, this is just an example.
```

After creating the model you will have the place to store ALL your records. I'll leave the storing task for you as an exercise.
Now, if you want to have 5 latest posts available to you, you need to create a method that will put 5 latest posts in an object
In your controller you will have to define a new method that will return an array of Post objects that will contain 5 latest posts.

```
def get_last_5
@last_five = User.find(:all, :order => "created_at desc", :limit => 5)
return @last_five #maybe an overkill but just to be sure
end
```

every time you run this method, it will return an array with 5 objects that were created latest. You can access them by calling `@last_five[0]`, `@last_five[1]` and etc.

Good luck!